# How c# asp.net read by separate between xml and string in xml node?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I got result from some system and don't know how to read by separate btw xml and string as below example.

```
<result>
    <xmldataHeader>
        <HeaderId>1</HeaderId>
        <xmldataDetail>
            <DetailId>1</DetailId>
            <DetailName>test</DetailName>
        </xmldataDetail>
    </xmldataHeader>success
</result>
```

expected result, it can read "success" or only xml in `<result></result>`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XML structure remains almost static as given in this question, you will be able to access the "success" text with `doc.SelectSingleNode("result").LastChild.OuterXml);`Please find the sample code below.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml($@"
                        <result>
                            <xmldataHeader>
                                <HeaderId> 1 </HeaderId>
                                <xmldataDetail>
                                <DetailId> 1 </DetailId>
                                <DetailName> test </DetailName>
                                </xmldataDetail>
                            </xmldataHeader> success
                            </result>");
            Console.WriteLine("Succes :" + doc.SelectSingleNode("result").LastChild.OuterXml);
            Console.WriteLine("xmldataHeader :"+doc.SelectSingleNode("result").FirstChild.OuterXml);
```

Comment: It's work ... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I dont totally understand your question. But if you want to separate all tags and get the individual data, you'll have to parse the xml.

One example is by using XmlReader in C#.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: thanks for your advise, my point is string "success" is in same node <result> which has xml result.

Comment: Yes, your result tag contains 2 items. Another tag (xmldataHeader) and a string (success). 
So when you parse the result tag, You should get two items a string and an object.

Comment: you got my point but sorry can you give me sample coding?